# How to determine the colors in a Custom style so I can apply them to a Custom Title Bar

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I am using a Custom Title bar (TTitleBar) primarily to place the Main Menu and a couple of drop downs onto the title bar.  This works without applying styles to my app but not when I apply Styles.

How can I discover the colors defines in a custom style so I can apply them to my CustomTitleBar.

I'm using Delphi 11.1

Answer (score 2):

TStyleManager.ActiveStyle.GetSystemColor(clActiveCaption) does the trick.